# c++ socket send don't transmit CR and LF

Tags: java, c++, sockets, winsock

Is there any solution to send CR (0x0D) and LF (0x0A) by socket?
I've got some data like the char buffer below. I want to have a solution where I'm able to send some binary data (range should be full 8Bit = 0x00 to 0xFF).
The socket "connectedSocket" is successfully set up.

```c
char bufSend[] = {0x01, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x04, 0x44, 0x0D, 0x12};
ret = send(connnectedSocket, bufSend, 7, 0);
if(SOCKET_ERROR == ret) {
    printf("Error: send, code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
```

I've got the return message: 10053 = WSAECONNABORTED

If I change the data to something without 0x0A and 0x0D there is no error.

The client is programmed in java:

```java
if (socket.isConnected()) {
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    socket.getInputStream()));

// start connection
out.println(CONNECTION_BEGIN);
inMessage = in.readLine();
System.out.println("data length: " + inMessage.length());
```

Comment: If you send binary data then you probably don't want to be using an `InputStreamReader` and `readLine` as these are fundamentally text oriented interfaces.

Comment: I concur with Charles. Your use case suggest you would be more inclined to use a simple `read(byte[])`. An `InputStreamReader` certainly doesn't seem appropriate since it by-definition is a "...bridge from byte streams to character streams" (from Sun's documentation), and by your own stated usage requirements, *not* what you want.

Comment: The `socket.isConnected()` test is redundant. If it wasn't connected you would have got a `ConnectException,` or you will get an exception when you try to get the streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your Java client to read more than a line. The problem is that Java is closing the connection.

Comment: can you describe why java is closing the connection?

Comment: Because you read one line and then stop. Unless you're doing something else after the code you've shown, your app likely then either exits or allows the stream to go out of scope and thus be garbage collected. Either of these cause the connection to be forcibly closed.

Comment: The probllem is that *the OP's application* is closing the connection, or the opeating system is when the process exits. Java doesn't spontaneously close conenctions.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending a line, you are sending binary data which happens to contain 0x0A and 0x0D, but not as line terminators. So don't read lines. Use `InputStream.read()`.

But it's hard to believe that sending this really produced ECONNABORTED and that removing two bytes fixed it.